# SQL: How can I get more than one row from a different table with join? (Beginner's question)

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables, one with places` names and one with phone numbers, for example. But each place can have more than one phone number.

When I try the code below, it duplicates the place and I get:

> Place 1 - First phone number
>
> Place 1 - Second phone number

And I want:

> Place 1 - First phone number, second phone number

So, I need the 'number' column to be an array with every number associated  with the place. As you can see, I'm not very good with SQL lol Thank you very much.

Table 1 - Places:

```
| id         | name        | address .    |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 1          |      Example|    Example   |
| 2          |      Example|    Example   |
```

Table 2 - Phones:

```
| id         | fgk_place   | number       |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 1          |      1      |    9999999   |
| 2          |      1      |    8888888   |
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT places.id, name, phones.number
FROM places
LEFT JOIN phones ON phones.fgk_place = places.id
```

What I'm getting:

```
1, Example, 9999999
1, Example, 8888888
```

What I need:

```
1, Example, [9999999, 8888888]
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Check out MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group_concat`

```
SELECT places.id, name, GROUP_CONCAT(phones.number)
FROM places
LEFT JOIN phones ON phones.fgk_place = places.id
GROUP BY  places.id, name
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want the phone numbers in order, then you should use the `ORDER BY` option in `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

In addition, you want to set the separator to `', '`.  The default is `','`, so you want the `SEPARATOR` option.

Assuming the ordering is based on the id column:

```
SELECT pl.id, pl.name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(ph.number ORDER BY ph.id SEPARATOR ', ') as numbers
FROM places pl LEFT JOIN
     phones ph
     ON ph.fgk_place = pl.id
GROUP BY pl.id, pl.name;
```